# How to achieve Single Logout using Thinktecture Identity Server3 and OpenId owin middleware for multiple ASP.NET MVC applications

Tags: identityserver3

I have 2 ASP.NET MVC applications and I am using the OpenID middleware **UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication** to do the single sign on to both. Configuration is described as below. SSO works great. I login from application 1 and then I check if I am logged into application 2 too that connects to idserver, I can see myself logged in. Both the client applications now have the same id_token and token.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "oidc",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookie",
        Authority = "<my-idserver-url>",
        ClientId = "client1",
        RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44360",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44360",                
        ResponseType = "id_token token",

       //scopes from config file
        Scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Scope"),

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
            {
                var claims = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
                var accepted_claims = new[]{"name", "tenant", "email", "sub"};
                var new_claims = claims.Where(x => accepted_claims.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();

                new_claims.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                new_claims.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(new_claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "email", "role");
                n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
```

On clicking logout in the app, when the RedirectToIdentityProvider method is invoked in the clients, I am setting the id_token as the IdTokenHint as below:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
            {
                if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                {
                    var user = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User;
                    if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        var id_token_claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "id_token");
                        if (id_token_claim != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token_claim.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
```

**Problem area > Single Logout:**

**Success Scenario:**
When I logout from the application 1, it redirects to idserver and logs me out and redirects me back to application 1. On debugging I can see that the signout message in the logout method of the DefaultViewService is not null in this case. This works great.

**Failure Scenario:**
The problem is when I try to logout from application 2 instead of application 1(remember that I logged in from application 1), it does take me to the logout page at idserver, and I can logout. But it does not redirect back to the application 2 and stays on the idserver logged out page. On debugging I can see that the signout message in the logout method of the DefaultViewService is null in this case.

Is it probably because the id_token was originally issued to the application1?

What am I missing?
Do I need to handle this kind of scenario and somehow get hold of the client in identity server, that the user used, to actually logout(application 2)? and then probably issue a new SignoutMessage and put in the postlogout redirect Url for that client?

Or I got it all wrong and this should work automatically?

**Update:**
A blunder was to try this out with everything on IISExpress localhost on different ports, both clients(locahost, different ports) somehow get the same id_token and access token which shouldn't happen.

Moving out to the IIS hosting different sites solved this and now the applications can get their own individual id_token and access token.

I am still working on the Single Logout, exploring the iFrame approach.

Comment: Have you achieved the single sign out? Can you please let me know how it should be done as I am also facing the same issue?

Comment: I dont know your issue or use case, but try avoiding IIS Express, make sure you get different Id_Tokens, and then everything should usually work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling on this myself for a few days.  Googling pointed me to your question :)

This is what I've done which worked for me (Not sure if this is the correct approach):

Added both Client Uris in the PostLogoutRedirectUris for each client configuration:

```
PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
{
    "http://localhost:28560/",
    "http://localhost:57311/"
}
```

Comment: I was just reading Brock Allen's post here https://brockallen.com/2016/02/08/single-sign-out-and-identityserver3/  and found out that the Versions after November 2015 have this out of the box, so you don't have to do the iFrame thing on your own now. It just picks all the PostLogoutRedirectUris values for that client from the database and creates an IFrame. Sadly I cannot upgrade yet because its related to a Membership Reboot upgrade too which I cannot afford to do at the moment. It will break multiple instances that are using this DB for me.